# How to get current location in google maps using "nativescript-google-maps-sdk"?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am building an app on nativescript+Angular2. I have downloaded the "nativescript-google-maps-sdk" plugin from npm. If I enable `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`, I get the "my-location" button on the upper right corner of the screen and clicking it takes me to my actual location.

What I would like to do is to get these coordinates programmaticaly, because I will need them for other operations (markers, proximity values etc.).
Ran through their code, but couldn't find how they are getting this current location. `gMap.getMyLocation()` is deprecated, so I can't use that, based on what's written here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap
We should be using FusedLocationProviderApi. If this plugin isn't using it, then how does it acquire current location?

Can anyone shed some light?

```
mapReady(args) {
    console.log("Map Ready");

    var gMap = args.gMap;
    gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // gMap.getMyLocation(); deprecated
    // need to get current location coordinates, somehow...
}
```

Comment: to be able to get current location you can use `nativescript-geolocation` plugin. For further help you can review this example - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/location/location-module-example.

Comment: I already was using the nativescript-geolocation plugin, to get my coordinates, but then it hit me - why would I need to use 2 plugins if gmaps already had a built in feature to locate you. I guess there is no way around this. Gona stick with it then, thank you. p.s. those examples are outdated I guess, seeing a "Location" plugin there, which is deprecated now.

Comment: With NativeScript 1.5.0 the `Location module` has been deprecated and has been moved to external plugin called `nativescript-geolocation`, which is supported from NativeScript developers team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, you can get your location from your device in 2 ways:

- with built in android LocationManager
- with google play services location module, which uses `FusedLocationProviderApi` which is built on default android LocationManager

The difference, from what I've read, is that the googles' version is more advanced - it switches from different location modes (gps, wifi) automatically and saves up your battery.

So, in order to use the googles' way, we need to:

Import google play services location module (+ means newest version):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
}
```

Then initialise the play services API:

```
declare var com: any;
GoogleApiClient = com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
LocationServices = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
var dis = this; // writing in typescript, so this is reference to our current component where this code will lay

// Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
if (this.googleApiClient == null) {
    this.googleApiClient = new dis.GoogleApiClient.Builder(application.android.context)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(new dis.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks({
            onConnected: function() {
                console.log("GoogleApiClient: CONNECTED");
            }.bind(this),
            onConnectionSuspended: function() {
                console.log("GoogleApiClient: SUSPENDED");
            }.bind(this)
        }))
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new dis.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener({
            onConnectionFailed: function() {
                console.log("GoogleApiClient: CONNECTION ERROR");
            }.bind(this)
        }))
        .addApi(dis.LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}

this.googleApiClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 2):

The nativescript-google-maps-sdk plugin doesn't support getting your location from the device.

You need to get the location from nativescript-geolocation ( you are already doing that) and then pass that to the google-map.

If you check the google-maps plugin's AndroidManifest.xml, it doesn't have the permission  to access the device's location.

Comment: `If you check the google-maps plugin's AndroidManifest.xml, it doesn't have the permission to access the device's location.` - It may not have a permission explicitly set there, but it still gets my location data when I set `gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`.